# Display custom post type taxonomy using args

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, args

I have a custom post type called 'staff'. Within this I have a taxonomy called 'team_name'. At the moment I have added one team called Corporate & Commercial Team (tag 6, slug corporate-commercial-team)

Here's my code in the template:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'staff',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'team_name',
      'field' => 'corporate-commercial-team',
      'terms' => 6
    )
  )
);
$staffs = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $staffs->have_posts() ) {
  while( $staffs->have_posts() ) {
    $staffs->the_post();
    ?>
      <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
    <?php
  }
}
else {
  echo 'Oh oh no products!';
}
?>
```

Here's my code in functions:

```
function team_name() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Team Name', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Team Name', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Teams' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Teams' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Team' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Team:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Team' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Team' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Team' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Team' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Teams' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'team_name', 'staff', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'team_name', 0 );
```

I have re-saved permalinks, and assigned this category to one of the posts but I'm getting 'Oh no no products!'

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconception of the parameters inside the `tax_query`. The `field` parameter is the particular column that should be searched and the column name should correspond with the actual term value being passed to the the `terms` parameter

The default for `field` is `term_id`. Whenever this parameter is omitted or set to `term_id`, `terms` should be an array or string of term **ID's**. The other values of `field` is `slug` and `name`, so you should pass an array or string of term slugs or names respectively to the `terms` parameter

Your `tax_query` should be

```
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'team_name',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => 6
    )
  )
```